# Unexpected behaviour when doing bitwise operations halving bitset space

Tags: java, binary, bitset

So I have for the longest time created "bitsets" in java.

I have always thought that if I use a long I have 64 bits to play with.

However I have now discovered it's not that simple...

And I suspect it has to with overflow and casting...

```
long x = 1<< 30;
return x+ "="+ Long.toBinaryString(x);
```

Renders:

> 1073741824=1000000000000000000000000000000

Expected.

But:

```
long x = 1<< 31;
return x+ "="+ Long.toBinaryString(x);
```

Renders:

> -2147483648=1111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000

?????

I assume it has to with how the long equivalent value of the binary shift is being calculated and then rendered as a long. i.e. it is cast to a long and then calculated and this is an overflow I assume...

I expected

> 10000000000000000000000000000000

and the long value to be some negative number (can't figure out what it is).

There is definitely 64 bits in a long in java... as

```
Long.toBinaryString(Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

Renders: 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 (64 1's).

How do I use the rest of the long space in my bitset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `1<< 31` is an `int`, equal to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, which you then widen to a `long`.

Make the first operand a `long`:

```
1L << 31
```

So this:

```
long x = 1L << 31;
return x+ "="+ Long.toBinaryString(x);
```

[Returns](https://ideone.com/qSuJDl):

```
2147483648=10000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: It's as simple as that!